# D3 Parsing a JSON nested array

Tags: arrays, json, parsing, d3.js, nested

Ahoy, looking for a little help:

I am taking sensor data from a microcontroller, sending it to a mysql database, and pulling it with `d3.json("tempdata.php",`

I realized that mysql has no good array support, and sending a single value at a time was worthless... So I had the idea to take many values over a known period, and send them as a single string. Said string is the 'accelX' string. I am absolutely flustered with figuring out how to parse the sub-array of accelX data...

I'd like to parse those values so I can update a graph with each consecutive iteration of accelX. 'id' is simply an automatically updating index. All three of these chunks are from a single sensor. 'id 1' is the first 30 values taken, 'id 2' are 31 - 61, and 'id 3' 32-62. If I can figure out how to separate them, I think I'll be in the clear.

Here's a little chunk of what "tempdata.php" returns:

```
[{"id":"1","date":"2015-01-02 22:33:20","temp":"16.7","accelX":"0.047,0.016,0.031,0.031,0.016,0.031,0.078,0.063,0.047,0.031,0.000,0.031,0.000,0.031,0.031,0.063,0.031,0.000,0.047,0.031,0.000,0.016,0.031,0.031,0.047,0.063,0.000,0.016,0.031,0.031,"},{"id":"2","date":"2015-01-02 22:33:28","temp":"16.7","accelX":"0.656,0.688,0.656,0.656,0.625,0.594,0.625,0.672,0.688,0.703,0.734,0.734,0.719,0.703,0.703,0.656,0.672,0.688,0.672,0.641,0.656,0.703,0.734,0.734,0.813,0.813,0.844,0.828,0.781,0.766,"},{"id":"3","date":"2015-01-02 22:33:34","temp":"16.8","accelX":"0.563,0.578,0.563,0.578,0.594,0.609,0.672,0.688,0.719,0.734,0.719,0.750,0.750,0.734,0.781,0.781,0.766,0.750,0.719,0.703,0.734,0.766,0.750,0.781,0.781,0.750,0.703,0.734,0.734,0.734,"}]
```

Comment: This isn't proper JSON.  Why not use PHP and turn `accelX` into an array, then send it as JSON and it's a javascript array.

Comment: you can run some loops on the accelX data field. but it won't be very quick.

Comment: Mark, please advise?